# Adding an XML file to my C++ project in NetBeans

Tags: c++, xml, netbeans

I am developing a graphics(OpenGL/GLUT/GTK) application in C++ using netbeans. I need to read some data from an xml file that is provided. How do I add this file to my project? I tried adding a new file to the project by right clicking and searching for new XML file. But there was no such option. What do I do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a generic 'file' and name it with a .xml extension. Either that or just copy it to someplace on the file system where it will be seen by the project.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project then click on :

> Add Existing Item..

And choose your XML file.